# Where can I find Java-EE configuration documentation such as faces-config?

Tags: jsf, faces-config, flow-scope

I'm new to Java-EE and I'm practicing Flow Scope in JSF.
I googled and also looked through Java-EE documentation and couldn't find any description for config tags.Where can I find documentation and description for config tags such as flow's inbound and outbound parameter and other xml configs?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did search engine really not come up with anything? What terms did you use?

Comment: And see [ask]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: yeah you're right but finding documentation for configs is a little bit tricky. I googled jsf config documentation or some thing like that you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best online documentation is probably on the JavaEE GitHub pages;

https://javaee.github.io/
https://javaserverfaces.github.io/docs/2.3/index.html

It's a bit scattered and it can be somewhat hard to find what you are looking for, but for documentation on configuration you can view the TOC of the Java EE tutorial pages;

https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/toc.html

For more in-depth information specific to faces-config and/or JSF configuration there is;

https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-configure.html#BNAWO

For a quick and official tutorial on flows, please check out;

https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-configure004.html#CHDGFCJF

The JSF PDF (which is also available on these pages, but can be a bit hard to find) is pretty great and includes 500 pages of mouthwatering documentation that covers almost everything related to JSF;

https://javaee.github.io/javaserverfaces-spec/downloads/JSF_2_3/Final/JSF_2.3.pdf

The FlowHandler and how inboun/outbound work is described in Chapter 7.

Comment: Remarkable isn't it, how a  search engine helps... but according to [ask]: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._  So you might stand chance the question gets closed and you effort is in vain

Comment: Yes, isn't it @Kukeltje ;) .. But depending a bit on your google-fu some of the official documentation can actually be a little tricky to find. The last PDF referenced is particularly useful and anybody into JSF should keep a local copy. I actually even have it printed.

Comment: The jsf for java-ee 8 book by BalusC is worth the buy

Comment: thanks Adam  for your grate answer.if such questions are off topics where can I ask them? does stackoverflow has the other part for these questions?

Comment: Good question @hamidreza75. I interpreted your question as asking about official documentation on the topic - which is not quite the same thing as recommending general reading on a topic. In this case there is no risk of opinionated bias. As you said, it can be quite hard to find what you are looking for merely just because of the scope of the documentation on offer. There's a lot of stuff in there. It does help when you have read it 10 times over though ;)